# How google is able of get our location so fast?

Tags: android, android-location

I have a Location Listener and I'm usin criteria to chose the best provider. I'm using 0 and 0 for min_distance and min_time for method requestLocationUpdates. And yet, my app is slow to get my atual localization. My app only get the atual localization one time to send to web. How can I it faster to get the atual location? The app Maps form google can dot so fast, even wit 3G.

Comment: you should use the new Location API https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: Is there any way of get the location quickly  without use Google Play Services?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Location as fast as possible try `getLastKnownLocation()` insteed of requesting updates. This is easy to do with the LocationClient. If you use the LocationManager you have to iterate over all Providers to get the most accurate Location. Reto Meier has a nice article about the use of the LocationManager in his [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html).

Note that before you can get a valid Location Object of getLastKnownLocation(), a update request is needed. Otherwise null will be returned.

Comment: But I want the atual location. If i use the getLastKnowLocation() it will get the last location. I want the atual location.